# Hide "Add event" button in calendar web part for read-only users

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, modern-pages

On our modern sharepoint online site, we have a calendar web part. For visitors, i.e. read-only users, the "Add event" button is grayed out. For our visitors, we'd rather remove the "Add event" button instead of just disabling it.

Is there a way to remove this button for users who don't have access to actually create new events?

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience, the SharePoint web part of modern experience cannot make such similar modifications.

In addition, even with the classic experience, we cannot disable buttons based on the user’s permissions.

In this situation, I suggest you use target audiences in the webpart attribute.

Only partially authorized users can see this webpart

[image]